# Listing Tables for several MXD documents using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects

I want to do a "Extending ArcObjects: Windows Application" app:

[image]

I have a code snippet that lists all the layers from the MXD files stored in a directory:

```
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles("C://path");
foreach (string fileName in fileEntries) {
            IMapDocument mapDoc = new MapDocument();
            mapDoc.Open(fileName);
            IMap map = mapDoc.Map[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < map.LayerCount; i++)
            {
                ILayer l = map.Layer[i];
            }
```

That part is working perfectly.

Now I need to list all the tables, but I don't know how to create the `IMxDocument` object I need for that. It looks like that with that method I can only get the Tables from the current document in an Add-In.

How can I get the Tables of the MXD files stored in a directory using ArcObjects?

I already know how to do this with ArcPy, but I really need to be able to do the same with ArcObjects.

Comment: Did you try casting map to `IStandaloneTableCollection`, then iterating ?

Comment: Thanks! Your comment took me in the right path. I get the `ActiveView` from the `IMapDocument` object. Then I perform a `FocusMap`in the `ActiveView` to get the `IMap` object. I cast the last one to `IStandaloneTableCollection` as you have told me and now I can get the list of tables.

Comment: Keep in mind an mxd can contain multiple maps.  I would iterate ... `for(int i=0;i<mapDoc.MapCount;i++)  map = mapDoc.Map[i]` instead.